# Use alt key to generate unicode chars

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, macosx, unicode

On MacOS, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key allows us to generate Unicode chars via regular keystrokes. For example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> → ∆ (Increment, U+2206).

Is there a way to alter my Ubuntu machine so that the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key does this?

Currently the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key doesn't seem to do anything when combined with letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "**English (Macintosh)**" layout instead of the standard English layout. Here's how it looks:

[image]

You'll need to use the "level 3 select key" (which is usually <kbd>AltGr</kbd> aka right-<kbd>Alt</kbd> key) to get those characters. For example, to get "**∆**" you need to press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> and to get "**½**" you need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>.

Comment: any way to do it with standard American layout?